# RecyclerView position not saved after screen rotation

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

RecyclerView position not saved after screen rotation and moves to the beginning of the list.
`RecyclerView` находиться в `Fragment`, added the following code to my project, after which, in theory, the position should be saved, but this does not happen

```
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        state = RLM_tasks.onSaveInstanceState();
    }
```

Help to figure out why the list does not save position and solve this problem
`Fragment` completely

```
public class FragmentList extends Fragment {
    CardView cv_list;

    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference collectionReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("Tasks");

    private AdapterTasksList adapterTasksList;
    private RecyclerView rv_tasks;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager RLM_tasks;

    Parcelable state;


    public static FragmentList newInstance() {
        return new FragmentList();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        cv_list = requireView().findViewById(R.id.cv_list);
        cv_list.setOnClickListener(v -> requireActivity().onBackPressed());

        Query query = collectionReference.orderBy("TurnTasks", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ItemTasks> firestoreRecyclerOptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ItemTasks>()
                .setQuery(query, ItemTasks.class)
                .build();

        adapterTasksList = new AdapterTasksList((ClickTasksBlanc) getContext(), firestoreRecyclerOptions);
        adapterTasksList.startListening();
        rv_tasks = requireView().findViewById(R.id.rv_list);
        RLM_tasks = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        RLM_tasks.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        rv_tasks.setHasFixedSize(false);
        rv_tasks.setLayoutManager(RLM_tasks);
        rv_tasks.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
        rv_tasks.setAdapter(adapterTasksList);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        state = RLM_tasks.onSaveInstanceState();
    }
}
```

I have suspicions that the whole problem is that the list is re-created when the screen is rotated, and therefore it cannot re-revert to the previous position.

Comment: try to add some delay with a handler or use `RLM_tasks.post(()->{ // restore here})` whenyou resotre the position. this is because the recyclerView has not yet created its views

Comment: i'm not sure but tried not to restore it before putting the adapter and the layout

Comment: Try to add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` attribute to the `<activity>` in manifest file

Comment: Have you read the [Restore RecyclerView scroll position blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/restore-recyclerview-scroll-position-a8fbdc9a9334)?

Comment: you are setting adapter again after rotation in the onViewCreated() i think is the reason of that behaviour

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan Where to install to make the problem go away?

Answer (score 0):

For these kind of situation you have to use model view- view model called mvvm you can get more detail & tutorial from official website and also see the some example of tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can save layoutManager state in ViewModel then get the state value when the fragment re-created

You can check the sample code here https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/android-jetpack-navigation-lost-state-after-navigation/#maintain-state-via-viewmodel